# How to render a partial view like in .Net Framework

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm actually a .Net programmer since I've finish studying.
For now, i want to train myself with PHP, so i've decided to learn this with the cakePHP framework.

I'm using the last version of this framework, but i've a little problem.

In Razor .Net, it's very basic to include a PartialViews in other view with the following method:

```
@Html.Partial('_MyPartialView', MyModel);
```

With this, coupled to JQuery and Ajax, it's easy to modify datas from a partial view without reloading all the page.

But now, i want to do this with CakePHP.
Because in my page, I have a table which i want to filter dynamically without reloading all the page.
I'm very beginner with CakePHP.

I've already created my view in a blank layout, with the table only displayed and pagined, which i can access calling controler name (eg : localhost/myapp/mytable/2) with all datas I want (I will manage filtering later).

But now, i can't understand how to render this view in my main page (eg : localhost/myapp/mypage/2) like it's easy to do in Razor .Net.

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS : I'm sorry if my english is bad... French power...

Comment: What about writing a controller that returns this partial view?

Comment: Yes, but how i can render it in the main view ? How i can call controller, or action like in .Net ?

Comment: Sounds like you should look into cells: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/cells.html**

Comment: I followed this tutorial, and used pagination. But i have errors like this : Notice (8): Undefined index: pageCount [CORE\src\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 1063]

And i don't know how to fix this error

Comment: It's good, i've found my mistake and all works perfectly